# Centralizing items on div with percentage width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a kind of "mosaic" on my site and he is inside of a div whose width is measured by percentage.

### The problem

How can I centralize content (to be more specific, *mosaic*) inside a div whose width is measured by percentage?

### The code

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="right">
            Some menu.
        </div>
        <div class="left">
            <ul class="list">
                <li>Showcase #1</li>
                <li>Showcase #2</li>
                <li>Showcase #3</li>
                <li>Showcase #4</li>
                <li>Showcase #5</li>
                <li>Showcase #6</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.main-container {
    background-color: #c19fe2;
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
}

.left {
    background-color: #ebd6ff;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}

.left li {
    width: 50px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    list-style: none;
}

.right {
    float: right;
    width: 270px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #8863ac;
}
```

**jQuery/JavaScript:**

```
/** Packery (jQuery Grid like Masonry/Prototype) **/
$(function() {
    var $container = $(".left");
    // initialize
    $container.packery({
        itemSelector: "li",
        gutter: 5
    });
});


/** Centralize the main container **/
function calculateMainContainerWidth() {
    $realWidth = $(".main-container").width() - $(".right").outerWidth(),
    $containerContent = $(".left");

    $containerContent.css("width", $realWidth);
}

$(window).on("resize", function() {
    calculateMainContainerWidth();
});

calculateMainContainerWidth();
```

### To debug, FiddleJS

[Just click here to go to the Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/dFfdf/4/)

### Technical details

The `calculateMainContainerWidth` function works fine — it is calculating the width of my container, but I can't use `margin: 0 auto;` to centralize perfectly. Of course there is a logical conflict behind this that is preventing me to centralize, but I would like to know what.

### References

The mosaic is made by [Packery, a Metafizzy's plug-in](http://packery.metafizzy.co/).

### Progression

Take a look at my own answer — the solution will be there.

Comment: I posted my answer before seeing your edit. I will update my answer accordingly soon.

Comment: No problem, bro. I had forgotten to specify details — sorry about it.

Comment: The source of the problem is that the jQuery module uses absolute positioning to place the `<li>` elements in the mosaic pattern.  The elements are placed left-to-right within the full with of the containing block, so the usual `margin: 0 auto` won't work.  You almost need some additional JavaScript to help out.

Comment: @MarcAudet Oh, thanks about the explanation. So, can you detail a little more about this "additional JavaScript"?

Comment: I am looking at it, the problem is that packery does not set the computed with of the parent container, that is, `.list`

Comment: Hmm... Sorry, but I did not understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a simpler solution for my headache.

I was using the [Packery's plugin, by Metafizzy](http://packery.metafizzy.co/) and after some research, I discovered that he doesn't have a centralized layout natively. Then, without hesitation, I switched to [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/), by the same creator, [Metafizzy](http://metafizzy.co/).

Unfortunatelly, at first I didn't find a solution. At first, seemed that the Isotope didn't have a centralization resource until I found [this extension](https://gist.github.com/beausmith/4760823), created by [Beau Smith](https://gist.github.com/beausmith), which centralizes and works with gutters. After all this, I got my mosaic centered. =)

I would like to apologize to those people who sought a solution for me, but either way it will be an alternative for those who have the same problem in the future. Thank you!

Comment: I did read up on Packery and they have an option called `stamped` which might have done the trick depending on the nature of your sidebar.

Comment: "Depending on the nature of sidebar" — The "depending" word it is the problem. With the extension, I can play calmly with the sidebar. Anyway, thanks about your entry again, @MarcAudet! =)

Answer (score 1):

### Partial Solution

I found a partial fix to the centering problem by adjusting the CSS as follows:

```
.left {
    background-color: #ebd6ff;
}
ul.list {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 330px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
ul.list li {
    width: 50px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}
```

The trick is to give a `max-width` to `ul.list` based on the maximum number of columns you expect (5 x 55px in this case).

With a maximum width, and using `margin: 0 auto`, the list will center in the `.left` container.

Also, it helps to zero out margin and padding since packery uses absolute positioning to place the elements.

Finally, apply the packery method to `.list` instead of `.left`.

Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/Nsm2Z/

**Limitation:** Once the widow size shrinks so that the `<li>` elements start forming two or more rows, there will be some extra white space on the right.   At this point, the layout is determined by the packery bin-layout algorithm and there is not too much that the
CSS can do since the `<li>` elements are positioned absolutely so out of the flow of the regular content, regular centering tricks won't work.

Comment: Marc, thank you very much about your entry, but I find a simpler solution yesterday. Sorry about this. =(

Comment: @chiefGui No problem! The important thing is that you shared your final solution which will help others.  All the best!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need all of the JavaScript and jQuery for horizontally centering a `<div>` in a container `<div>`. I usually just go with a div that has margins like this:

```
#centeredContent
{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Hello, Cameron. Thanks for your entry. So, I also like to use `margin: 0 auto;`, but the mosaic isn't centralizing and I don't know why. To more details, see the fiddle.