# Responsive menu with title: have a resizing title that takes up all available space

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

Consider this situation: i have a page with a title and a menu bar, aligned in the same row. The site is responsive, and i want the title and the menu to both have the most optimal width available.

However, the menu should never collapse and should always take all available space. The title *can* collapse, but should use all available width for as long as possible.

This might be a little vague so i created a jQuery solution right here:

http://cdpn.io/tBskv

Try resizing your browser window so that the menu overlaps with the title to understand what i mean.

However, i would *really* like a CSS solution without any Javascript. Preferably it should work on IE8, but i'm willing to have some compromises if there is a solution that is for modern browsers only.

Comment: Do you mean something like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/S2U26/)?

Comment: @SpYk3HH: Not quite.. In your example the containers have a fixed width (even though it has a percentage), which means the 'loose space' will be assigned to the menu. If you have the page at a reasonable width the title should be on one line and not break. Please have a look at the example and resize the browser window to understand what i mean.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually possible with CSS, and in IE8 when using `display:table-cell` and `white-space:nowrap` appropriately. I posted the CSS solution to your problem at

http://codepen.io/anon/full/HhCFB

This solution allows the menu on the right to never collapse and the title on the left to be full title width, or collapse in the available width when the page gets too small.

In short:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <span>a long example title</span>
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<style>
    .wrap {
        display: table;
    }

    span {
        display:table-cell;
    }

    ul {
        display: table-cell;
        white-space: nowrap;                   
    }

    li {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }
</style>
```

The `display:table` and `display:table-cell` make sure that both the title and menu act as columns so they won't float underneath each other. The trick to not letting the menu collapse is using `white-space:nowrap` on the `ul`. Now, when the page gets too small, the title will be the only one to line break.

In the codepen solution link mentioned above, there is also a variation added that makes sure the title span will never get bigger than it's content's width. This way the menu will also stick to the title. Just comment out `.outer{ float:left }` to get the code solution mentioned in this answer.

Kinda what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with CSS only — not if you want to work with IE8.

You have to calculate the available space to fill the divs within, and the calc()'s function just work on modern browsers.

I created two topics to search a responsive solution to percentage containers, and the results are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926958/centralizing-items-on-div-with-percentage-width/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16985488/when-resize-the-divs-width-back-to-normal/).

The JavaScript's  final solution is this:

```
/** Centralize the main container **/
function calculateMainContainerWidth() {
    $realWidth = $(".main-container").width() - $(".right").outerWidth(),
    $containerContent = $(".left");
    $containerContent.css("width", $realWidth);
};

$(window).on("resize", function() {
    calculateMainContainerWidth();
});

calculateMainContainerWidth();
```

Also available in [FiddleJS](http://jsfiddle.net/dFfdf/4/).

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and i would actually like to use `calc` because it works in all browsers, except for IE8. However, it seems you can't use `calc` to get the width of another element, so i don't really see how you could use as a solution....

Comment: The calc is `$(".main-container").width() - $(".right").outerWidth()`. You have to adapt to your problem. And plus: my objective was to show the situation for you, not the code.

Comment: Right.. but what you're showing here is a jQuery solution, not a CSS solution. The solution i provided in the codepen link is the same as yours...

Comment: As I said, Husky: `Unfortunately, this is not possible with CSS only — not if you want to work with IE8.`

Comment: Okay, but what would be the CSS solution then? It doesn't need to work in IE8.